# Is there any solution to handle dataType for TestCaseSource ? [Nunit Framework]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

Based on https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/data-driven-tests-with-nunit/ website. I have try to create a simple testcase which prepare for read data in the future. But I have no idea how to handle Argument and use it properly

I have try to set as a object, but i think this might not be a correct solution

```
        [TestCaseSource("GetDataString")]
        public void TestMethod2(object configs)
        {


        }
```

Here is source code

```
namespace SAP
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Scenario1
    {

        // This one Give System.ArgumentException 
        [TestCaseSource("GetDataString")]
        public void TestMethod(List<Config> configs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Config " + configs);

        }
        // This one can handle an Exception
        [TestCaseSource("GetDataString")]
        public void TestMethod2(object configs)
        {


        }

        public static List<Config> GetDataString()
        {
            var datas = new List<Config>();             
            datas.Add(new Config("Nick", "Coldson"));
            return datas;
        }
    }

    public  class Config
    {
        public string NickName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Config(string nickname, string name)
        {
            NickName = nickname;
            Name = name;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is error msg

> System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'SAP.Config' cannot be
>   converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SAP.Config]'.

Comment: Have a look at official [sample](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) You should pass objects of exact type for your tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The testcasesource has slightly different definition pattern. Assuming you use nunit 3 it should be:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(MyTestData), nameof(GetDataString))]
public void TestMethod2(List<Config> configs)
{
   ...
}

public class MyTestData
{
    public static IEnumerable GetDataString()
    {
        var datas = new List<Config>();             
        datas.Add(new Config("Nick", "Coldson"));

        return new TestCaseData(datas);
    }
}
```

For more info, check the documentation:
https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData

Comment: I have look up a documentation. It works perfectly. Just adding **yield** and *get*.  However, I don't stand keyword **yield**. What does it mean ? Any purpose for usage ?

Comment: Yield is just a lazy way of returning an enumerable, instead of returning full collection of test cases you basically pass them one by one. This enables you to do minimal changes, but you do not need to use it if you plan to make 1 test case per test only.

Answer (score 2):

Your `GetDataString` returns a `List<Config>`.

Meaning, your test method with a `[TestCaseSource("GetDataString")]` will be executed as many times as many items the list has and your method must match the item type.

```
//// This one throws System.ArgumentException 
//[TestCaseSource("GetDataString")]
//public void TestMethod(List<Config> configs)
//{
//    Console.WriteLine("Config " + configs);
//}

// This one is ok
[TestCaseSource("GetDataString")]
public void TestMethod(Config config)
{
    Console.WriteLine(config);
}
```

If you need to get `List<Config>` instances in your test, then your source must return some collection containing list items.

Comment: I have plan to Test Data in Excel file , so **GetDataString()** will be implemented to read all Data in Excel. I want to let manual tester prepare data for testing by filling information in Excel. When the test case is running, it will retrieve all data in excel as they provide